# Prove a cone $S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=0, x_3 \ge 0 \}$ is a convex set.

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-cone

I have to prove a cone
$$S=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=0, x_3 \ge 0 \}$$ is a convex set.

The definition of a convex set is known as

"A set $C$ is convex if for $x,y \in C$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ then $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in C$".

I try to use this definition to prove S is a convex.

First, for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3) \in C$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, let $z=\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y$.
Then $$z_1^2+z_2^2-z_3^2  = \lambda^2 (x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2) +2\lambda(1-\lambda)(x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_3y_3) +(\lambda(1-\lambda))^2(y_1^2+y_2^2-y_3^2). $$

Since $x,y \in S$ then
$x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=0, y_1^2+y_2^2-y_3^2=0$.

My problem is that I don't have any way to prove $x_1y_1+x_2y_2-x_3y_3=0$.

One way I have tried is that
$$|x_1y_1+x_2y_2| \le \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}=x_3y_3. $$

Comment: $(1,0,1)\in S$, $(0,1,1)\in S$. But $(1/2,1/2,1)=1/2(1,0,1)+1/2(0,1,1)\notin S$, so it is not convex.
Do you mean $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2\le 0$?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, thank you, I think Ihave my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the cone representation in spherical coordinates through
$$
{x_1=R\sin\theta\cos\phi
\\x_2=R\sin\theta\sin\phi
\\x_3=R\cos\theta
}
$$
and prove the convexity using the new representation.